# Delete title of popover bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am working on a project that uses bootstrap
My question is:
How can I delete the title of `popover`

This is my code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        });
</script>

  <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Some content">
         CLICK HERE
    </a>
```

And this is the resultset

[image]

This is resultset I want

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the attribute title from your anchor tag

`<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Some content">CLICK HERE</a>`

Comment: It's not working, there is a blank space instead of title !

Comment: It's working for me. Are you sure you deleted the tag and not only the content of it?

Comment: Just copy paste the tag I wrote

Comment: I'm copy and past your code, title is removed but space blanc it still remains

Comment: I don't know what's happening with your code, but look at this. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18172/ (The css styles are just for the demo)